# php mysql PDO update

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to update the MySQL row with the following code. This does not work and the values remain the same. Where am I wrong? I have made the analogy of the "?" format from other cases not exact:

```
$fname_upd=$_POST['fname'];

$lname_upd=$_POST['lname'];

$email_upd=$_POST['email'];

include('connection.php');

$q_ins="UPDATE myguests SET (firstname, lastname,email) VALUES(?,?,?) WHERE id=?"; 
$ins=$dbh->prepare($q_ins);

$res=$ins->execute(array($fname_upd,$lname_upd,$email_upd,$id));

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written wrong query.
Below is the corrected query:

```
$q_ins="UPDATE myguests SET firstname=?, lastname=?,email=? WHERE id=?"; 
$ins=$dbh->prepare($q_ins);
```

Read php PDO manual.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check this updated code**, but let me know where you have defined $id variable because it is the variable on the basis of which we are updating the values.

**What i did?**

I have updated update query of yours with placeholder values and also make use of isset() function to check our $_POST values.

```
<?php

$fname_upd = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';

$lname_upd = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : "";

$email_upd = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

include('connection.php');

$sql = "UPDATE myguests SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname, email = :email WHERE id = :id";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $fname_upd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lname_upd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email_upd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

And also you need to update your used syntax because it is not correctly used which i have updated as

```
 <?php

    $fname_upd = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';

    $lname_upd = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : "";

    $email_upd = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

    include('connection.php');

    $q_ins = "UPDATE myguests SET firstname=?, lastname=?,email=? WHERE id=?";
    $ins = $dbh->prepare($q_ins);

    $res = $ins->execute(array($fname_upd, $lname_upd, $email_upd, $id));
    print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `execute()` does anything with it's arguments. If you want to keep the `?` syntax, what you can do with a prepared statement is [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) before executing. So your code would look more like.

```
$q_ins="UPDATE myguests SET (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES(?,?,?) WHERE id=?"; 
$ins=$dbh->prepare($q_ins);
$ins->bind_param('ssss', $fname_upd, $lname_upd, $email_upd, $id);
$res=$ins->execute();
```

The first argument of the `bind_params()` tells the prepared statement what types to expect. You might want to change the `'s'` for the `$id` to an `'i'` depending on how `$id` is defined, but in my experience, it won't actually matter.